# How to call a component from 2 diiferent routes in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular-component-router

I have a `userDetails` component that can be accessed from two different pages in my application.

It can be accessed from `searchUser` component and I have a "my account" menu in the header that is available across the application and it is in `MenuComponent`. I should take the user to the user details page from search page as well as my account menu. I'm using `router.navigate` to navigate to the details page. It's working fine from the search results page.

However, when I click the "My account" link it is hitting the `userDetails` component and when it hits the function that calls the service to fetch the data it is not calling the API and comes out of the function and takes me to the homepage. The URL is same from both the places.
I used `console.log` to log the `activatedroute.routeconfig.path`, it is `/users/:userId` when I call from search results and `/home` when I call from MyAccount link.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please share the code. Ideally a minimal reproduction using http://stackblitz.com

Comment: it's in the subscribe when you must navigate to page: in pseudocode, http.get("API").subscribe((data)=>{this.router.navigate(data.id))